# How do you change Word´s view to Web Layout?

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to know for a homework, please answer if you know. I haven´t tried anything because I really don´t know.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching Word's Help system. Open Word, hit F1 or click the blue question mark in the upper right. Search for "web layout".

Answer (score 0):

Go to View in the main menu then Web Layout.